# creating strongly typed custom helpers for img tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm trying to create custom Html Helpers in my sample MVC Project.

Here is what i've done so far:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageFor<TModel,TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>> expression,
            string alternateText,
            object htmlAttributes) 
        {
            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", metadata.Model.ToString());
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
```

In my controller I'm passing the image path to a property(imgUrl).

When i try to create a tag for it it doesnot give me the `image` on browser, instead it is always displaying the alternate text.

Here is the rendered markup for it.

```
<img name="imageUrl" alt="alernate" src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\down.png"/>
```

While i've done the loosely typed helper for `@Html.Image`, it works perfect !.

What has gone wrong with my code.

I've searched alot for creating `Strongly Typed Helpers`, but none of the tutorials explained me what is going on when we access the strongly typed helpers.

I've also seen posts in SO, when someone post code regarding helpers, its just a piece of code without any explanation.

If anyone has a tutorial for creating strongly typed custom helpers, which gives a breif of please share the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src` attribute points to your local drive. That is not going to work. Your browser displays the alternate text because it can't find the image. You should use the *URL* of the image instead. For example `src="/images/down.png"`.

Comment: +1 Oh. I just forgot to peep into that issue. Thanks. Can you post any tutorial if you have for creating strongly typed custom helpers, that provides a breif of what is going on in the background.

Comment: See [Custom strongly-typed HtmlHelpers in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389747/Custom-strongly-typed-HtmlHelpers-in-ASP-NET-MVC) for some guidelines.

Comment: I've seen it already. I've got some video on msdn. Thanks. Accepting as answer

Comment: Here is another resource on strongly typed helpers. It has code examples and illustrations. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/writing-custom-html-helpers-for-asp.net-mvc/